# How to implement Checkpoint on the below scenario

Tags: ssis

I have one simple ssis package which transfers data from one table to another table and same way we have 5 table has about 50 million rows each and all 5 tables are independent control flow tasks in package.

by considering scenario like network failure or low memory or incorrect data , package will fail.

So I'm trying to implement checkpoint.suppose 4 tables succeeded and one table failed after inserting 40 million rows.

If I re-run the package , only remaining 10 million rows for the failed data flow task should insert and other tasks which succeeded in last try will not execute.

Please reply.

Comment: if task are in sequence then it will be implemented easily but this "only remaining 10 million rows for the failed data flow task should insert and other tasks which seceded in last try will not execute. can not achieved" with checkpoint

Comment: Thanks Sandeep. Is there any way to handle this kind of scenario.

Comment: if possible to process load in batch  and have have track .